# sbcl: list all valid character encodings

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, common-lisp, sbcl

To get the list of all valid encodings for sbcl, I do this:

```
(let (encoding-list)
  (let (symbol-list)
    (do-external-symbols (s :keyword)
      (push s symbol-list))
    (setf symbol-list (sort symbol-list #'string<))
    (mapc (lambda (x)
            (when (ignore-errors
                    (with-open-file
                      (phyle "scratch1"
                        :direction       :output
                        :if-exists       :supersede
                        :external-format x)
                      1))  ; <-- produce something non-NIL
              (push x encoding-list)))
          symbol-list))
  (nreverse encoding-list))
```

Is there an easier way to do this in sbcl? (For example, in clisp, all the encodings are external symbols in the CHARSET package.)

Comment: What purpose do you need the list for? The manual has a [list](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#External-Formats) if you just want to see which ones are available. Internally SBCL seems to have a hash-table `SB-IMPL::*EXTERNAL-FORMATS*`, which contains all external formats.

Comment: @jkiiski : I'm writing a LISP program to explore all the formats, just for fun. My LISP program can't read the manual. Your suggestion worked, and (not surprisingly) produces the same formats as in the manual; if you make it a real-live answer, I'd be happy to accept it. My kludgey way produces the same output except that it also includes "DEFAULT".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only "official" list is in [the manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#External-Formats). If you don't mind looking into SBCLs internals, external formats are stored in a hash table, `SB-IMPL::*EXTERNAL-FORMATS*`.

```
CL-USER> (alexandria:hash-table-keys sb-impl::*external-formats*)
(:UTF32BE :UTF-32BE :UTF32LE :UTF-32LE :UTF16BE :UTF-16BE :UTF16LE :UTF-16LE
 :UCS4BE :UCS-4BE :UCS4LE :UCS-4LE :UCS2BE :UCS-2BE :UCS2LE :UCS-2LE :CP932
 :|Shift_JIS| :SJIS :SHIFT_JIS :|eucJP| :EUCJP :EUC-JP :CP936 :GBK :|macintosh|
 :MACINTOSH :|mac| :MAC :|MacRoman| :|mac-roman| :MAC-ROMAN :|windows-1258|
 :WINDOWS-1258 :|cp1258| :CP1258 :|windows-1257| :WINDOWS-1257 :|cp1257|
 :CP1257 :|windows-1256| :WINDOWS-1256 :|cp1256| :CP1256 :|windows-1255|
 :WINDOWS-1255 :|cp1255| :CP1255 :|cp1254| :CP1254 :|windows-1253|
 :WINDOWS-1253 :|cp1253| :CP1253 :|windows-1252| :WINDOWS-1252 :|cp1252|
 :CP1252 :|windows-1251| :WINDOWS-1251 :|cp1251| :CP1251 :|windows-1250|
 :WINDOWS-1250 :|cp1250| :CP1250 :ISO8859-15 :ISO-8859-15 :LATIN9 :LATIN-9
 :|latin-8| :LATIN-8 :|iso-8859-14| :ISO-8859-14 :|latin-7| :LATIN-7
 :|iso-8859-13| :ISO-8859-13 :|iso-8859-11| :ISO-8859-11 :|latin-6| :LATIN-6
 :|iso-8859-10| :ISO-8859-10 :|latin-5| :LATIN-5 :|iso-8859-9| :ISO-8859-9
 :|iso-8859-8| :ISO-8859-8 :|iso-8859-7| :ISO-8859-7 :|iso-8859-6| :ISO-8859-6
 :|iso-8859-5| :ISO-8859-5 :|latin-4| :LATIN-4 :|iso-8859-4| :ISO-8859-4
 :|latin-3| :LATIN-3 :|iso-8859-3| :ISO-8859-3 :|latin-2| :LATIN-2
 :|iso-8859-2| :ISO-8859-2 :|cp874| :CP874 :|cp869| :CP869 :|cp866| :CP866
 :|cp865| :CP865 :|cp864| :CP864 :|cp863| :CP863 :|cp862| :CP862 :|cp861|
 :CP861 :|cp860| :CP860 :|cp857| :CP857 :|cp855| :CP855 :|cp852| :CP852
 :|cp850| :CP850 :|cp437| :CP437 :|x-mac-cyrillic| :X-MAC-CYRILLIC :|koi8-u|
 :KOI8-U :|koi8-r| :KOI8-R :IBM037 :IBM-037 :|cp037| :CP037 :EBCDIC-US :UTF8
 :UTF-8 :ISO8859-1 :ISO-8859-1 :LATIN1 :LATIN-1 :|646| :ISO-646-US :ISO-646
 :ANSI_X3.4-1968 :US-ASCII :ASCII)
```

Of course, since this is not a public API there is no guarantee that it won't be broken in future releases.

Comment: Since this is not a public API, your cautionary note is appreciated. I can always fall back to my first-proposed kludge if necessary. But thanks also for alerting me to sb-impl. Lots of other (possibly temporary, but I'll take my chances) goodies in there.